# Is it possible to customize rolify methods like has_role? , add_role etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

How does rolify works and is it possible to customize rolify methods like has_role? , add_role etc..

Comment: Yes, you can.  Can you describe what you're trying to achieve, maybe show some sample code you want implemented?

Comment: Sure, it's ruby, you can customize everything. In your case, it's as simple as defining methods `has_role? / add_role` in your model. Just don't forget to invoke the parent implementation.

Comment: i have DIM_ROLE oracle table with role_name(primary key), role_description,create_timestamp and update timestamp columns. similarly i have dim_user with some columns along with role_name column and role_user_map with user_id and role_name. How to use rolify gem with this? i don't have resource id and resourse_type columns in my db.Neither users_roles table i have. Can u please help me on how to proceed?

Comment: Looks like it would be better for you to write your own implementation from scratch, instead of using rolify.

Answer (score 1):

Working of `rolify` gem, you can prefer [doc](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify). I could not get why you want to alter method names which are more preferable.

You can use `alias_method` inside respective model class also for your need.

Comment: But how to define alias_method for resource_type and resource_id column which i currently don't have in my database

Comment: I am asking to use `alias_method` for `has_role` & `add_role`